# Map numbers to text in Power BI with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling with a DAX formula that uses IF..ELSE. I have numeric data which will be mapped to the reason for employee absenteeism (text) as outlined below.

- **0:** incomplete submission
- **1, 2, 3, 4:** family related
- **5-25, 27, 28:** medical reasons
- **26:** unjustified leave

I have tried the following DAX formula:

```
Absenteeism reason = IF(OR(Absenteeism [Reason for absence],0,"incomplete submission",==,1-4,"family related"))
```

I didn't complete the rest of the formula, as I got the following error:

> message unexpected parameter ',"incomplete submission" ==,1-4,"family related",))

How can this mapping be achieved?

Comment: Your formula is a total mess. Use a sample data to show what your input is and the desired results you want to get.

Comment: Hello, did my answer solve your issue? If so would you mind accepting it as the solution and upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to create the mapping using a [SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) statement as outlined in the DAX below.

If you're creating a **Calculated Column**:

```
Absenteeism reason = 
VAR reason = Absenteeism[Reason for absence]

RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE, 
        reason = 0, "incomplete submission", 
        reason >= 1 && reason <= 4, "family related", 
        reason >= 5 && reason <= 25, "medical reasons", 
        reason >= 27 && reason <= 28, "medical reasons", 
        reason = 26, "unjustified leave", 
        ""
    )
```

If you're creating a **Measure**, which will then be added to a table visual:

```
Absenteeism reason = 
VAR reason = CALCULATE(MAX(Absenteeism[Reason for absence]))

RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE, 
        reason = 0, "incomplete submission", 
        reason >= 1 && reason <= 4, "family related", 
        reason >= 5 && reason <= 25, "medical reasons", 
        reason >= 27 && reason <= 28, "medical reasons", 
        reason = 26, "unjustified leave", 
        ""
    )
```